# Prove the Extremal Value Theorem: Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that $C$ is compact...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove the Extremal Value Theorem: Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $C$ is compact. Prove that there exists a point in $v \in C$ such that $f(v)=$$\min_{x\in C}f(x)$.

I know there are many ways to prove the Extremal Value Theorem, but not too sure how to get started on simpler proof than the page-long one I have...

Answer (score 1):

The continuous image of a compact space is compact. Compact subsets of $\mathbb R$ are closed and bounded so they contain a minimum.